# "In a while" or "for in a while"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

Ok, Which one is correct from the three below ?

1. I have not had a drink in a while.
2. I have not had a drink in for a while.
3. I have not had a drink for a while.

In case more than one are correct then are they interchangeable or mean different things in different context ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for "I can't get a drink now", I don't get what "I have not had a drink" means.

Comment: @Mattew : huh? :O

Comment: What "I have not had a drink" means? You mean "I  didn't drink" or "I hadn't a drink" maybe?

Comment: "I have not drank alcoholic beverages."

Comment: Oh ok. I suggest you to edit the post..

Comment: @Mattew : Oh I don't think so. Except for the possible grammatical mistake in one or two of the three, this sentence is perfectly alright and  being used everyday. Every English speaking person would understand.

Comment: No problem, Have a nice day

Comment: @Mattew : I just saw you are German.  I guess you are here for learning too. At first I had thought you were some English-speaking man from your name and it seemed a little strange that you did not understand what I meant. But now it's ok. :)

Comment: I"m German, Mattew is a nickname

Answer (score 1):

Either 1 or 3 is acceptable and interchangeable.  You might hear one more than the other in some areas, but hey mean the same.  #2 the "in for" becomes redundant and spoils the sentence.